# Does Greater Restoration also end the effects cured by Lesser Restoration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing

The [*lesser restoration*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lesser-restoration) spell description states:

> You touch a creature and can end either one disease or one condition afflicting it. The condition can be blinded, deafened, paralyzed, or poisoned.

The [*greater restoration*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration) spell, on the other hand, says:

> You imbue a creature you touch with positive energy to undo a debilitating effect. You can reduce the target's exhaustion level by one, or end one of the following effects on the target:
>
> - One effect that charmed or petrified the target
> - One curse, including the target's attunement to a cursed magic item
> - Any reduction to one of the target's ability scores
> - One effect reducing the target's hit point maximum

The *lesser restoration* spell ends paralysis, but this is not listed in the effects that *greater restoration* can cure.

It makes sense to me that a Greater version of a spell does everything the Lesser version does (and more!), but what is RAW in this case?

Comment: This also implies Greater Restoration doesn't cure diseases either; it could end specific effects of the disease, but only Lesser Restoration claims to end a disease at all.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[**Spells only do what they say.**](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret)

Greater Restoration does not alleviate the conditions ended by Lesser Restoration, because it does not say that it alleviates the conditions ended by Lesser Restoration.

Sidenote. As GR uses a 5th level slot and only ends one effect, it wouldn't make much sense for a character to use it ahead of LR, which uses a 2nd level slot and ends one condition, to end paralysis, barring situations of one being prepared ahead of the other.

Comment: Actually it might make sense to use GR if it were allowed, as a cleric has a limited number of spells that they can prepare. Using GR when LR would do could be wasteful if the character  had lower-level slots available. But preparing *both* GR and LR could be wasteful if a situation requiring LR did not occur.

Comment: Greater Restoration also has a material component consumed by casting with a gp value. I don't think 100gp is prohibitively expensive, but it's likely that a cleric wouldn't be carrying an *infinite* amount of diamond dust with them so GR will often have a limited number of uses on a larger scale as well.

Comment: Considering that diamonds are essentially a form of currency that players might very well carry around at level 9, the real question is "what is a portable method of crushing diamonds to dust?"

Comment: @Rogem Whack 'em with a hammer? Diamonds are hard, sure, but they're also brittle. Your hammer will lose that perfect mirror polish that it probably doesn't have, but a chunk of iron or steel will fare much better in an impact than a chunk of diamond.

Answer (score 5):

My impression of 5e is that most spells are made not to overlap so much (exceptions exist). In previous editions, “greater” did have a tendency to mean “in addition to”, but this time around I think the idea is to separate them so you don’t burn a higher level spell when a lower would suffice. It means the lesser spell does not become obsolete once greater is available.